# Connecting to MySQL from Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, connection

I'm trying to connect to the MySql database from a Java servlet. I'm working in Eclipse IDE.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/try", "root", "password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (request.getParameter("select1") != null) {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String select1 = (String) request.getParameter("select1");
        int no = Integer.parseInt(select1);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM try.try where id='" + no + "'";
        out.print("<option>---select one---</option>");
        try {
            Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.print("<option>" + rs.getString("output") + "</option>");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In the line

`con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/try", "root", "password")`

I get the following exception:

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/try Exception.`

I downloaded the connector/J, extracted the jar file into Tomcat library folder and set it in the class path.

I have no idea what else I could have done wrong. It also says

```
The JAR file C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar has no source attachment.
```

I thank for any help in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the URL is incorrect. It should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/try
          ^-- you missed the colon here
```

Just putting the jar file of the driver in your WEB-INF/lib folder should be sufficient. No need to modify the Tomcat installation. But you should really take care of closing the resultsets, statements and connections in a finally block, else your database will quickly run out of available connections.

You should also use a pooled DataSource as explained in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

Comment: I corrected closing but the main problem is still unsolved even though I put the connector into WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Have you refreshed the project under Eclipse? Do you see the jar of the driver under the Web App Libraries node?

Comment: Yes I did...but nothing changed

Comment: Oh thank u. Such a stupid mistake (that I'll remeber forever now :-D ).thank u for help again